# Hinting abstract classes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an array of classes, all of which extend from a base abstract class. If you'll forgive the terrible and overused OO abstractions:

```js
abstract class Animal {
  abstract speak(): string;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  speak(): string {
    return "woof... sigh"
  }
}

class Cat...
```

I have an array which encapsulates all of these implementations:

```js
const all = [Cat, Dog];
```

I want to tell TypeScript that everything in this array will, on construction, return a class that is an instance of Animal.

It's important to note that this is passing around the class, not the object, so this would be invalid as the classes themselves don't inherit from the abstract.

```js
const all : Array<Animal> = [Cat, Dog]
```

I unfortunately can't seem to find anything in the docs about typehinting through the new keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to declare a value which, when called with `new`, returns an `Animal`. This is written as:

```
new() => Animal
```

Note the similarity to function types (`() => Animal`).

The full code is then:

```
const all: Array<new() => Animal> = [Cat, Dog];
```

Or, using an interface for clarity:

```
interface AnimalConstructor {
    new(): Animal;
}

const all: AnimalConstructor[] = [Cat, Dog];
```

Comment: This will work so long as they don't extend the dog or cat class. Once those classes are extended they won't match the signature of  Animal.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!  I also have no intention of extending the abstract further Budhead, but thank you for your ahead-of-time warning!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
const all: (typeof Animal)[] = [Cat, Dog]
```

Comment: I would like to note that you might have to do an `extend Animal` to get this to work properly

Comment: Thanks! The lack of `extends Animal` was a typo on my partk This change has resolved the typehinting issue, but possibly too well :P TypeScript now thinks that creating an instance from that array is equal to trying to do a create from an abstract class, rather than acknowledging that I'm trying just trying to insantiate something with that interface.

Comment: You should be able to cast to the correct class by doing `new (all[0] as typeof Cat)()`

Comment: But this approach kind of defeats the purpouse of the typing system. To me it sounds a little like this solution with classes in an array is an suboptimal approach. There could be a more elegant solution available.